# redirect the page on Java script function alert box (OK) click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

below is my java script function on aspx page

```
<script>
 function alert6() {
            alert("You Can't Delete This Record");
        }
</script>
```

and use the function on my cs page, i want to redirect the page after the user clicks on OK what i Need to do?

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert5", "alert6();", true);
```

Comment: The question is not clear.Why  r u registering the client script??

Comment: this is how i used to do it in cs, is this wrong?

Comment: In your event handler itself you can call Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer to redirect to other page.Why to trigger a client side script for that??

Comment: @bhanu.cs sir actually on my cs i used if else condition like 

`if()
{
Function
}
ELSE
{
Another Function
}`

Comment: Thats fine but how is it related to,not using Response.Redirect?? Update with your server side code function to understand better.

Comment: actually i used response.redirect but it is not redirecting to other pages, I want both function and redirecting to other page but i can only use one of these

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124960/discussion-between-ibrahim-shaikh-and-bhanu-cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply if you want to redirect the page just after clicking on Ok button of alert box then try this

```
<script>
 function alert6() {
  alert("You Can't Delete This Record");
  window.location="Your page";
        }
</script>
```

and call it

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert5", "alert6();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge on ASP .NET. But as I understand, you are trying to print out a javascript function to the page which would redirect the page when the OK button is clicked.

As you said you are using JQuery you can use the function below. I am assuming the id of the OK button is 'btnOk'.

```
$("#btnOk").click(function(){
   window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
});
```